# Enable GSS-Negotiate with curl

Tags: php, curl, single-sign-on

I have the following issue.

OS: CentOS 6.6

PHP: 5.5

Curl: 7.43 compiled

When I execute "curl -V" I get the following:

```
curl 7.43.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.43.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1e zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.0 nghttp2/1.2.1-DEV
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: Debug TrackMemory IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz HTTP2 UnixSockets
```

What I need is curl to support "GSS-Negotiation" but no matter what I try it does not shows up in the features list.

What am I doing wrong?

For example on another server with CentOS 6.4 it is running correctly:
Curl -V

```
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.0.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

I am using SSO for my project and the idea is to send the credentials to an API.

Answer (score -1):

You have two separate builds of cURL, one for each server.  To upgrade, there are a few options:

1. Build an updated version yourself by [downloading the source code](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html).
2. Upgrade using [`yum`](http://yum.baseurl.org/) from the command line:

   ```
   yum clean all
   yum install libcurl
   ```

Option 1 is probably the better route for you since you can control exactly which modules are included within your build.